# Add subview from a xib or another scene with storyboard

Tags: ios, view, storyboard

I'm new to iOS and Xcode.
I can't figure out how to design a separated view and make it be added into the main UIViewController using storyboard.

I did different approaches..

1. Just grab an UI object from right-bottom corner window in the xcode, and then put it onto  any space area of storyboard. But I can't drop the UI object like the way with xib.
2. Add a new UIViewController. Add a view into the `UIViewController`. In the main ViewController.m, I get the new `UIViewController` instance in the viewDidLoad, and then `[self.view addSubview:newUIViewController.view]`. But I can't see the added view.
3. I created a new xib file. And add a view into it. I also try to get the instance in the main `ViewController`. And `addSubview` with the xib's view. But it also failed.

Is there a correct way or any working solution to do so?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I create a custom iOS view class and instantiate multiple copies of it (in IB)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9251202/how-do-i-create-a-custom-ios-view-class-and-instantiate-multiple-copies-of-it-i)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I figured out a way to do it.
Described as following:

1. Create a .xib file. For example: MyView.xib
2. Create a objective-c class. For example: MyViewClass.h and MyViewClass.m
3. Set the .xib File's Owner to the class.
4. Add a UIView element on the storyboard and set the custom class to the objective-c class name (MyViewClass).
5. The key-point is to override the **initWithCoder** method in the object-c class.

   ```
   - (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
       if ((self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder])) {
           [self addSubview:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0]];
       }
       return self;
   }
   ```

The idea is the custom class is loaded by the storyboard and initWithCode will be called.
The index 0 is the root view in the .xib interface builder.

It's kind of tricky but it works.

Comment: I do something very similar, but I don't do `owner:self` because I don't want all the outlets/action/code for my XIB embedded in my view controller (and normally I want to re-use in many places). I create a subclass of a `UIView` then `alloc` and `init` that subclass and set that to be the owner.

Comment: Your code sample is actually instantiating two copies of your view, one by the storyboard when it calls `initWithCoder:` and your call through to super, and another when you call `loadNibNamed:` to load the view from the nib. What you _actually_ want to be doing, which is even more hacky, is `self = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyView" owner:self options:nil][0]` in your initWithCoder method, and _not_ call through to `[super initWithCoder:]`

Comment: @AlexPretzlav : it seems like when you want to return a different self, a "NSGenericExpection : this coder requires that replaced objects be returned from initwithcoder" is raised. So you really have to add it as a subview.

Comment: doesn't this create 2 views? one in the storyboard and one on code? 
Becuase one its created in the Storyboard and one its created at the initcode.  According to what I have tested, it seems two are created.

Comment: You saved my day and my yesterday :D

Answer (score 0):

In storyboard, drag and drop a view controller. The view controller come with a main view. Select that main view by clicking outside of the added view controller and then clicking in the center of it. Now, just drag a uiview or whatever into that main view just like you did with IB.

Comment: That's what I did in the 2nd approach. But I can't see the added view.