# Reuse views of multiple UIStoryboards

Tags: iphone, storyboard, uistoryboard

I use multiple storyboards in my iOS app and now have the problem that one view shall be reused between multiple storyboard-files.

Is there any way to do that?

Thank you for your help,

Christian

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create reusable views to use in multiple storyboard-files, you'll want to fall back on using nibs, and programmatically instantiate and add the views from the nibs to your storyboard views. See this answer for more commentary: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8495940/195691

Here's another (slightly hacky) approach to doing this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11444019/195691